# how to run multiple processes by using same binary file in one machine

Tags: linux, process

I built a golang binary file, I wanna run it parallel by using this file, but I have only one machine, how to run it meanwhile?

Comment: Run it in the background `./app&` this way you can run it many times at the same time.

Comment: okay, let me check, thank u

Comment: Just run it in different terminal windows. But if you export ports, makes sure that ports different in those terminals.

Comment: how to make sure run with different ports? seems I never run it by a specific port, it's automatically set by linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your process in the background:

```sh
$ ./binary &
[1] 12345
# When that process is done you'll get notified:
[1]  + done       ./binary
```

To run your process along side in your workspace, you can use tmux, [click here for a tmux toturial](https://edricteo.com/tmux-tutorial/).

Also I'm not quite sure why having only one machine stop you from having two terminal emulators open and running your program twice, if your program is using databases and parallel processes will cause issues, then that's the code not about linux or your machine.

Comment: this is a script, I wanna run multiple processes with different params, so same code but affect different data, to make it done more quickly, I wanna run them at the same time. yeah u are right my program is using database but read different rows if I pass different params as I said, only one machine can access this database, that's why I have to use one machine